# Exit from infinite loop if it performs operation too long

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

I have a function that send command and then in infinite loop read data in from `USB` device with completion callback:

```
func dump(success: (() -> Void)? = nil, failure: (()->Void)? = nil) {
    HIDDevice.sharedInstance.sendCommad(command: "dump")
    while true {
        for data in HIDDevice.sharedInstance.readBuf {
            if data == "dumpcomplete":
               success?()
               return
        }
    }
}
```

And i need to check if this while loop works `> 1` second and didn't get success, then call `failure` closure and stop loop.

I tried to use this before loop, but it didn't help. Thread blocks by loop.

```
func setTimeout(delay:TimeInterval, block:@escaping ()->Void) -> Timer {
    return Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: delay, target: BlockOperation(block: block), selector: #selector(Operation.main), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

let handle = setTimeout(1, block: { () -> Void in
    failure()?
    return
})
```

Comment: Busy loops are bad. Does `readBuf` block or simply return if there is no data?

Comment: @rmaddy i have this class: https://github.com/bettse/KuandoSwift/blob/master/KuandoSwift/BusyLight.swift#L20

and only way to read data in `ViewController` is to read from temporary variable

Comment: @arti btw you can compact your assignment of `r`, `g`, and `b` down to one line: `let (r, g, b): (UInt8, UInt8, UInt8) = (0, 0xff, 0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I don't think such "busy loops" are a good idea, I don't know anything about `HIDDevice` so I can't offer an alternative to such a loop. So this answer only addresses the direct question of how to exit the `while` loop after 1 second.

One possible solution is to calculate a time interval and check that each time:

```
func dump(success: (() -> Void)? = nil, failure: (()->Void)? = nil) {
    HIDDevice.sharedInstance.sendCommad(command: "dump")
    let deadline = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate + 1 // add one second from now
    while Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate < deadline {
        for data in HIDDevice.sharedInstance.readBuf {
            if data == "dumpcomplete":
               success?()
               return
        }
    }
}
```

This calculates a time interval in the future and checks the current time against that future value. Once that time has passed the `while` loop will exit.

Comment: I think I have a better solution: use GCD with a timeout. Never used GCD before, so it'll take me a second to play around before I answer

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov thank you, will wait for GCD. Yes i know ```while loop``` is looks awful, but it is only one way to read data from device properly.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov i have this class: https://github.com/bettse/KuandoSwift/blob/master/KuandoSwift/BusyLight.swift#L20

and only way to read data in `ViewController` is to read from temporary variable

Answer (score 2):

## Using Grand Central Dispatch

rmaddyy's answer works, but the constant sampling of the current time gets really expensive.

As an alternative approach, I suggest you multithread. Here's a function that performs the looping for you, and stops looping after a timeout. It also returns a `DispatchTimeoutResult` notifying you if the loop ended successfully, or timed out.

```
import Dispatch

func BusyLoop(timeout: DispatchTimeInterval,
              qos: DispatchQoS = .background,
              _ block: @escaping @convention(block) ( () -> Void ) -> Void) -> DispatchTimeoutResult {
    var shouldLoop = true;
    let BreakLoop = { shouldLoop = false } //callback to stop looping
    
    let item = DispatchWorkItem() {
        while shouldLoop {
            block(BreakLoop)
        }
    }
    
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Busy Loop", qos: qos) //TODO: Name me
    queue.async(execute: item)
    
    let state = item.wait(timeout: .now() + timeout)
    if state == .timedOut {
        shouldLoop = false
    }
    
    return state
}

var i = 0

BusyLoop(timeout: .seconds(1)) { BreakLoop in
    //treat this as the loop body
    print(i)
    i += 1
    
    if i == 1000 { BreakLoop() } //treat this as "break"
    // "return" acts as "continue"
}


switch timeoutResult {
case .success: print("Finished on time")
case .timedOut: print("Timed out")
}
```

Here's a sample implementation for your case:

```
func dump(success: (() -> Void)? = nil, failure: (()->Void)? = nil) {
    HIDDevice.sharedInstance.sendCommad(command: "dump")
    
    let timeoutResult = BusyLoop(timeout: .seconds(1)) { BreakLoop in
        for data in HIDDevice.sharedInstance.readBuf {
            switch data {
                case "dumpcomplete":
                    success?()
                    BreakLoop()
                default: BreakLoop() //handle other cases
            }
        }
    }

    switch timeoutResult {
    case .success:
        print("Finished on time")
        success?()
    case .timedOut:
        print("Timed out")
        failure?()
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this leaks the WorkItem. It will keep running, using the processor, etc., you just won't be waiting on it and you won't be able to get the result. Unless you somehow check that it's cancelled (like rmaddy does), you can't avoid that problem. There's no way to abort a block from outside the block (there are very good reasons for that; there's no way to do it safely in Swift).

Comment: @RobNapier Oh yeah, I hadn't considered that. Hmm shit, got any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: rmaddy's answer. No matter how you build it, eventually you're going to need a "should we stop?" in the while loop's conditional. (Obviously there are ways you could make that more generic if you wanted to, but this kind of looping probably isn't something to spend a lot of time making generic; it's not a typical Swift pattern.)

Comment: @RobNapier I rewrote my answer. What do you think?